# My value1.length is receiving a length undefined error. The value2.length and value3.length aren't receiving errors

Tags: javascript, dom

Value1.length is sending a undefined error however the other two values are not. Why is it only the first value isn't running properly?

```
placeOrder.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var value1 = input1.value;
    if (value1.length < 1) {
        value1 = 0;
        coffeeTotal = 0;
    } else {
        coffeeTotal = coffeePrice * parseInt(value1);
    }

    var value2 = input2.value;
    if (value2.length < 1) {
        value2 = 0;
        bagelTotal = 0;
    } else {
        bagelTotal = bagelPrice * parseInt(value2);
    }

    var value3 = input3.value;
    if (value3.length < 1) {
        value3 = 0;
        biscottiTotal = 0;
    } else {
        biscottiTotal = biscottiPrice * parseInt(value3);
    }

    var total = coffeeTotal + bagelTotal + biscottiTotal;
    console.log(total);


});
```

Comment: What is `input1, input2, input3`?

Comment: Where is the value of *input1* assigned and what is it supposed to be? The use of *parseInt* in `coffeePrice * parseInt(value1)` is redundant since multiplication will coerce the arguments to type number anyway.

Comment: var input1 = document.getElementById("coffee");
var input2 = document.getElementById("bagel");
var input3 = document.getElementById("biscotti");

Comment: Please add `console.log(document.getElementById("coffee"));` first to see if that DOM element could be found

Answer (score 0):

**What does typeerror: cannot read property “values” from undefined really mean?**

To understand this, you first need to understand what it means to be undefined in JavaScript. Let’s take a look at a simple example using variables:

```
// This line is a variable declaration
// we create it, but do not assign it a value 
// so it is undefined
var a; 
// In this line we declare and assign a variable
// this is not undefined 
var b = 6;
```

Something is undefined when it is an object that is expected to hold a reference to a value, but in fact references nothing.
So you have to check your input1's value.